# Breadth First Graph Traversal Given an Adjacency Matrix Using an Iterator

Tags: java, iterator, breadth-first-search, adjacency-matrix

Given a square adjacency matrix and a starting point, how do you traverse it using a breadth first method. I am lost, can someone please give me an example of what the code should look like? I understand the concept of breadth first, but do not know how to implement it.

Comment: This is not the place to ask how to get started. Research and come back with specific questions once you've tried things.

Answer (score 0):

1 Take a starting point, mark it as used and add it to a queue.

2 Take a point out of your queue. If this point is the target then your location is reachable; exit. If it is not then use this point in step 3

3 Look each square next the point. For each square if the square is not used then mark it as used and add it to the back of the queue.

4 If queue is not empty then go back to step 2

5 If the queue is empty and target is not found then target is not reachable from starting point used in step one